# method in python that does post and get

Tags: python, http-post, get-request

I've created a method that received a request with parameters as well as 2 additional parameters in the url the url looks like this:

```
url(r'^courseid=(?P<course_id>\d+)/user_id=(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', views.user_data_on_course, name='userDataOnCourse'),
```

the function looks like this

```
def user_data_on_course(request, course_id, user_id):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       <Extract the data and save to DB>
   else if request.method == 'GET':
       <Return the data>
```

when I add the `else if request.method == 'GET':`  I get error 500 on every method that is being called, and the DEBUG info is `Exception Value: invalid syntax (views.py, line 308)` which is the line of the else if

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In python use `elif` instead of `else if`

Here the doc : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

The python if statement structure is:

```
if a:
    b
elif c:
    d
else:
    e
```